# Is there a way inform a user of success/error when inserting into MYSQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I was wondering if there is a way to relay information to a user via a Toast message of success/error when inserting data into a MYSQL database. The application I am developing on is Android, the back-end is being handled by PHP and the data is being inputted to the database using Volley. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting data in MySQL, it returns `true` or `false` based on success or failure of inserting data. You can send this value in response and in Android based on this value it can display `Toast`.